# Why is the big O time complexity for this questions is C?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

[The screenshot of the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rrs8W.png)

My calculation is:

```
 statement              | time 
------------------------|--------
var value = 0;          | 1
for(var i=0;i<n;i++)    | 1 + (n+1) + n 
for(var j=0;j<i;j++);   | n + n*(n(n+1)/2 +1) + n* n(n+1)/2
value += 1;             | n*(n(n+1)/2
```

Comment: is that semi-colon after second loop intensionally put ??

Comment: It's not in the image, so probably not

Comment: `j` runs from 0 to `i - 1`.  That makes `i` iterations. Hence the total number of iterations is the sum `0 + 1 + 2 + ... + (n - 1) = n(n - 1)/2`

Comment: Is the question about total number of statements being evaluated (including e.g. the comparison and increment in the loops), or how often the `value += 1` line is executed (and hence what's the final value of `value`)?

Comment: @Ronald Your comment is the answer. Please consider converting it to an answer by enlarging on the topic and using a technical answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take the initial few iteration counts and see.

```
i (counter)           j (# of iterations for each value of i)
0th                   0
1st                   1
2nd                   2
.                     .
.                     .
(n-1)th               n-1
```

Now the sum of first N integers is defined as `n(n+1)/2` where the range starts from `1` and goes till `n`. More details [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF).

In our case, range starts from `0` and goes till `n-1` (RHS in the above table). Replacing `n` with `n-1` in the summation formula, you get `n(n-1)/2`.

Comment: A detailed explanation on the formmula can be found  [here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/sum-of-n-n2-or-n3/)

Answer (score 0):

The Big O complexity is O(n*n), so n squared.

The number of operations is n(n-1)/2.

The Big O complexity ignores constants and lower order terms.

Answer (score 0):

The question is poorly formulated and thus has no precise answer. Indeed, the author did not say which operation "counts". For example, when i=0, the inner loop is executed once (at least initialization and test), while its body is not.

Now if we only count the number of incrementations of value, the innermost loop performs exactly i of them, and the outer loop makes i vary from 0 to n-1. Hence a total of Tn-1 = n(n-1)/2 (triangular number).

Comment: I think it means the upper bound time complexity, which is the inner loop.

Comment: @NicholasC.: that does not better the question, and the upper bound is certainly not "the inner loop".